# How to make a css valid to all browsers?

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

I defined these css styles :

```
.scrollbar {
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
}
.scrollbar-primary::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.scrollbar-primary::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #4285F4;
}
```

At runtime it runs only on Google Chrome. When I run the app through Mozilla Firefox then the app does not render properly the desired rendering. So how to make the styles applied for all browsers ?

Comment: There's a lot of resources to help you figure this out simply by searching for it. What have you researched so far?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot implement this CSS across all browsers. `-webkit` is a vendor prefix for browsers that support either the WebKit or Blink browser engine. Right now support is inconsistent even within browsers that support this prefix:

[MDN Documentation for ::-webkit-scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

[CanIUse Documentation for ::-webkit-scrollbar](https://caniuse.com/#search=webkit-scrollbar)

If you absolutely need a fully customized scrollbar implementation that is fully cross-browser compatible you will very likely need to research a JavaScript based solution.

The good news is that since this is a vendor prefix, browsers that do not support it will simply ignore the declarations and load the scrollbar in whatever fashion that browser normally displays its scrolling mechanism.

Comment: Interesting side note...the majority of Windows browsers supported customized scrollbar colors back in the early/mid 2000's.